# Looping a list of objects by inserting their data into a table with columns as input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, for-loop

I'm trying to cycle a list of objects, for each object present in it I would like to insert a row in a table.

The problem I'm having concerns the columns of the table that I want to represent as editable input, I can't insert the correct data.

The "Date Rata" input field for all rows appears to take the Data Rata value from the last object in the rateList, rather than the specific Date Rata value for each.

This is an image that represents the situation (leaving aside the date formatting). As you can see, the DataRata value of the last object present in rateList is inserted but I can assure you that each one has its value correctly set within the list.

I am using Angular 11.
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row mt-3 col-md-12" *ngIf="pianoGenerato && pianoQuotaSelected">
  <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-sm-12">
    <form class="webcau-form" [formGroup]="pianoRientriForm">
      <div class="webcau-yellow-border-2 mb-4">
        <div class="form-page-container m-3">
          <div id="accordingpianoQuota" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <webcau-prodotto-section-title
              [htmlReference]="'PianoQuota'"
              title="Piano Rate dal {{pianoRientriSceltaForm.get('DataPrimaRataPiano')?.value | date: datetime.DATE_ANGULAR_VIEW_FORMAT}}"
              titleClass="h4">
            </webcau-prodotto-section-title>
          </div>
          <div id="QuotaPiano" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingPianoQuota">
            <div class="mx-0 px-0" style="margin-top: 30px;">
              <div class="col-md-12 mx-0 px-0">
                <div class="table-responsive container-fluid">
                  <table class="table webcau-table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <th scope="col">Azione</th>
                        <th scope="col">Numero Rata</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data Rata</th>
                        <th scope="col">Importo Rata</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quota Capitale</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quota Interesse</th>
                        <th scope="col">Debito Residuo</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor="let rata of rateList; let i = index">
                        <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" style="height: fit-content">
                            Seleziona
                          </button>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">{{rata.NumeroRata}}</td>
                        <td align="center">
                          <input placeholder="" type="text" class="input-group form-control webcau-yellow-border-1"
                                 formControlName="DataRata"
                                 [(ngModel)]="rata.DataRata">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                          <input placeholder="" type="text" class="input-group form-control webcau-yellow-border-1"
                                                   name="importoRata"
                                                   formControlName="ImportoRata"
                                 [(ngModel)]="rata.ImportoRata">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">{{rata.QuotaCapitale}} €</td>
                        <td align="center">{{rata.QuotaInteresse}} €</td>
                        <td align="center">{{rata.DebitoResiduo}} €</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 my-2" *ngIf="pianoSelected">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-1" style="height: fit-content" (click)="cancellaPiano()">
              <fa-icon [icon]="utilityService.faIconSelect('faTimes')"></fa-icon>
              Cancella Piano
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

typeScript:

```
public generaPianoAQuotaCapitaleCostante(
  importoTotaleDaRateizzare: number,
  importoRataAcconto: number,
  dataDiAcconto: Date,
  dataPrimaRata: Date,
  incrDateRata: number,
  tassoDiAmmortamento: number
): void {
  const numeroRateAnnuali = Number(this.pianoRientriSceltaForm.get('NumeroRateAnnualiPiano')?.value);
  const numeroRateTotali = Number(this.pianoRientriSceltaForm.get('NumeroRateTotaliPiano')?.value);
  const quotaCapitaleAcconto = 0;
  const debitoResiduo = importoTotaleDaRateizzare;
  let debitoResiduoSuccessivo: number = 0;
  let debitoResiduoPrecedente: number = 0;
  let dataRataSuccessiva: Date | null = null;

  this.rateList.push({
    NumeroRata: 'Acconto',
    DataRata: dataDiAcconto,
    ImportoRata: Number(importoRataAcconto).toFixed(2),
    DebitoResiduoIniziale: null,
    QuotaInteresse: null,
    QuotaCapitale: quotaCapitaleAcconto.toString(),
    DebitoResiduoFinale: null,
    DebitoResiduo: debitoResiduo.toString()
  });

  for (let i = 0; i <= numeroRateTotali - 1; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      const rata = {
        NumeroRata: (i + 1).toString(),
        DataRata: dataPrimaRata,
        ImportoRata: Number((debitoResiduo / numeroRateTotali) + (debitoResiduo * tassoDiAmmortamento / numeroRateAnnuali)).toFixed(2),
        DebitoResiduoIniziale: null,
        QuotaInteresse: Number(debitoResiduo * tassoDiAmmortamento / numeroRateAnnuali).toFixed(2),
        QuotaCapitale: Number(debitoResiduo / numeroRateTotali).toFixed(2),
        DebitoResiduoFinale: null,
        DebitoResiduo: Number(debitoResiduo - quotaCapitaleAcconto).toFixed(2),
      };

      dataRataSuccessiva = new Date(dataPrimaRata?.getFullYear(), dataPrimaRata?.getMonth() + incrDateRata, dataPrimaRata?.getDate());
      debitoResiduoSuccessivo = Number(parseFloat(rata.DebitoResiduo) - parseFloat(rata.ImportoRata));
      debitoResiduoPrecedente = Number(parseFloat(rata.DebitoResiduo));
      this.rateList.push(rata);
    } else {
      if (dataRataSuccessiva !== null) {
        const rata = {
          NumeroRata: (i + 1).toString(),
          DataRata: dataRataSuccessiva,
          ImportoRata: Number((debitoResiduo / numeroRateTotali) + (debitoResiduoPrecedente * tassoDiAmmortamento / numeroRateAnnuali)).toFixed(2),
          DebitoResiduoIniziale: null,
          QuotaInteresse: Number(debitoResiduoPrecedente * tassoDiAmmortamento / numeroRateAnnuali).toFixed(2),
          QuotaCapitale: Number(debitoResiduo / numeroRateTotali).toFixed(2),
          DebitoResiduoFinale: null,
          DebitoResiduo: debitoResiduoSuccessivo.toFixed(2)
        };

        dataRataSuccessiva = new Date(dataRataSuccessiva?.getFullYear(), dataRataSuccessiva?.getMonth() + incrDateRata, dataRataSuccessiva?.getDate());
        debitoResiduoSuccessivo = Number(parseFloat(rata.DebitoResiduo) - parseFloat(rata.ImportoRata));
        debitoResiduoPrecedente = Number(parseFloat(rata.DebitoResiduo));
        this.rateList.push(rata);
      }
    }
  }

  this.openDati = false;
  this.pianoGenerato = true;
}
```

I tried to use other directives than ngModel but the result did not change, actually the values ​​are not even inserted into the inputs

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the index you set :

```
<input placeholder="" type="text" class="input-group form-control webcau-yellow-border-1"
       [(ngModel)]="rateList[i].DataRata">
```

Note that you shouldn't use ngModel AND formControl in the same form.